# Launch application after PackageInstaller finished (self) updating

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, device-owner, packageinstaller, cosu

After the PackageInstaller successfully (self) updates the application, the application closes and doesn't launch again.

Possible duplicate: [Android PackageInstaller, re-open the app after it updates itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940990/android-packageinstaller-re-open-the-app-after-it-updates-itself)

The situation is pretty similar, ill show some code snippets first.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My PackageInstaller session runs in an AsyncTask:

```
PackageInstaller packageInstaller = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
        PackageInstaller.SessionParams parameters = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
        parameters.setAppPackageName(StaticData.TerminalPackageName);

        progressChanged(10);

        try {
            int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(parameters);
            PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);

            ProgressApproximatorHandler progress = startProgressApproximator(10, 100, 5);

            OutputStream installerStream = session.openWrite("INSTALL_TERMINAL", 0, mApplicationLength);
            installerStream.write(firmwareData, 0, mApplicationLength);

            // This call ensures every byte on the stream is committed to disk.
            session.fsync(installerStream);
            installerStream.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, UpdateReceiver.class);
            intent.setAction(Intents.APK_INSTALL_FINISHED_INTENT);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    mContext.get(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Sealing the session.
            session.commit(pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
            session.close();
            progress.stop();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.error(mLogTag, e, "Failed to create an installer session.");
            return false;
        }
```

At the end of this snippet, you can see the setup of an Intent to send. I've tried many variations and none of them worked. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.APK_INSTALL_FINISHED_INTENT);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED");
```

My receiver never receives the intent.

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "UPDATE";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Logger.info(TAG, "Intent action: " + intent.getAction());
        Logger.info(TAG, "updated");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Somehow I managed to restart the app autimatically but it gets killed after a 1-3 seconds. I found the following error in the logcat of the system.

```
W/ActivityManager: Unable to send startActivity intent
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED from pid=-1, uid=10071
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18195)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:18777)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:308)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendWithResult(PendingIntentRecord.java:205)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.sendIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:7409)
        at android.content.IntentSender.sendIntent(IntentSender.java:190)
        at android.content.IntentSender.sendIntent(IntentSender.java:154)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService$PackageInstallObserverAdapter.onPackageInstalled(PackageInstallerService.java:1069)
        at android.app.PackageInstallObserver$1.onPackageInstalled(PackageInstallObserver.java:34)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerSession.dispatchSessionFinished(PackageInstallerSession.java:1137)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerSession.-wrap2(PackageInstallerSession.java)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerSession$4.onPackageInstalled(PackageInstallerSession.java:648)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.handlePackagePostInstall(PackageManagerService.java:1809)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap25(PackageManagerService.java)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$PackageHandler.doHandleMessage(PackageManagerService.java:1438)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$PackageHandler.handleMessage(PackageManagerService.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I am not sure if this is the reason for it.

EDIT2: Now I receive the intent, thus the app is running. The problem now is that its in the back stack.

I have a launcher app that **could** re-launch the main (updated) app but that doesn't sound clean code to me.

EDIT3:

I tried David's answer but I receive the following error:

```
E/ActivityManager: Failure starting process com.example.myapp
    java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.example.myapp is currently frozen!
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.checkPackageStartable(PackageManagerService.java:3197)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3789)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3749)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3630)
        at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:1255)
        at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$BroadcastHandler.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:172)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Note this is thrown by the android system, and not by my app.

Comment: The `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` `Intent` is broadcast by Android after your app is updated. Is the install/update successful?

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes it was successful. I Edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` `Intent` is broadcast by Android after your app is updated.

To restart your app after the update, you could pass a launch `Intent` to the `PackageInstaller`, like this:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext.get(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
session.commit(pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
```

This should cause your app to be restarted after the update is completed.

Comment: The ActivityManager throws an exception. I edited the question according to this.

Comment: It looks like something is trying to start your app while Android is still in the middle of doing the update.

Comment: But if you are using an `Intent` to have the `PackageManager` restart your app you probably don't need to respond to the `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcast. Try removing that and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

While David Wasser's answer was probably the right one. I am closing my case because I'm having very strange and undefined behaviour, and I am pretty sure that's because I am using a custom ROM

Comment: This is not really an answer. You should edit your question and add your comments to that.

Comment: @DavidWasser You are right, I'll write a longer explanation of what worked for me a little bit later. Thank you for your input.